# Get Specific Data From Server With Page Number In Mud Blazor

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I use mud blazor
[MudBlazor Table](https://mudblazor.com/components/table#server-side-filtering,-sorting-and-pagination)
my table have one million records.

I want get data from API with specific page number . if i show all of records its busy and low opreation .

I want when user click page number 10  , call api to get 100 to 150 records.

how can i set function for page number mud blazor

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Mudblazors Table documentation https://mudblazor.com/components/table#server-side-filtering,-sorting-and-pagination

Use the `ServerData` attribute on MudTable with

```
<MudTable ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<Element>>>(ServerReload))" ... >
```

and

```
private async Task<TableData<Element>> ServerReload(TableState state)
{
   // API call with Page and PageSize
}
```

You get the `Page` and `PageSize` from the `TableState`.